# Request_BadRequest in O365

Tags: javascript, office365api

I am trying to send a email with the help of O365. I have configured everything but I am getting a error

> GraphError {   statusCode: 405,   code: 'Request_BadRequest',
>   message: 'Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request
>   target.',   requestId: '34f321-57de-4483-b97d-5957f8786ecb',   date:
>   2019-09-16T00:17:53.000Z,   body:
>   '{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Specified HTTP method is not
>   allowed for the request
>   target.","innerError":{"request-id":"34f803b1-57de-4483-b97d-5957f8786ecb","date":"2019-09-16T05:47:51"}}'
>   }

**Code**

```
const APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const APP_SECERET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const TENANT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token";
const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
const GRANT_TYPE = "client_credentials";
const graphScopes = ["User.Read", "Mail.Send"]; // An array of graph scopes

const request = require("request");
const endpoint = TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
const requestParams = {
    grant_type: GRANT_TYPE,
    client_id: APP_ID,
    client_secret: APP_SECERET,
    scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE
};
request.post({
    url: endpoint,
    form: requestParams
}, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
    } else {
        // console.log(response);
        // console.log("Body=" + body);
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
        } else {
            console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
            // testGraphAPI(parsedBody.access_token);
            let accessToken = parsedBody.access_token;
            getMe(accessToken);
        }
    }
});

function getMe(accessToken) {
    require("isomorphic-fetch");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client").Client;
    const options = {
        defaultVersion: "v1.0",
        debugLogging: true,
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, accessToken);
        },
    };

    // https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/samples/node/main.js
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview

    const client = MicrosoftGraph.init(options);

    // send an email
    const sendMail = {
        message: {
            subject: "Test o365 api from node",
            body: {
                contentType: "Text",
                content: "Testing api."
            },
            toRecipients: [{
                emailAddress: {
                    address: "test@abc.com"
                }
            }],
            ccRecipients: [{
                emailAddress: {
                    address: "test@abc.com"
                }
            }]
        },
        saveToSentItems: "false"
    };

    client.api('/users/test1@abc.onmicrosoft.com ').post(sendMail).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it was a malformed url when sending to the users.

I think your url should be `/users/test1@abc.onmicrosoft.com/sendMail`